# Cost and Performance Impact by joining on MD5 value of tables instead of Primary Key

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to Join two tables (Stage and Target) for Change Data Capture. While Joining the table i have two options,

1. Join on each column part of the Primary Key(STG.KEY_1=TGT.KEY_1 AND STG.KEY_2=TGT.KEY_2)
2. Join based on the MD5 value of the Key Columns(MD5(STG.KEY_1||STG.KEY_2)=MD5(TGT.KEY_1||TGT.KEY_2)

Will there be a difference in performance and cost?

I tried both ways with a table of 100k records but using History Tabs stats there is not much of a difference.

Logically PK KEY join makes more sense, but is there any way to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Using natural keys can sometimes have a performance advantage over hashes, but only if a number of conditions are met.

Snowflake [partition pruning](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#query-pruning) happens at two levels, one during compile and one on execution. Generally compile-time pruning is going prune more micro-partitions than execution time pruning. Pruning on join happens during execution. If you use natural keys, such as simple increasing integers, and if you filter at least one table before the join, then there's a chance the other table will benefit from execution-time pruning (aka dynamic pruning) too. For example if you have a join that restricts one side to a month's worth of data and that has a natural order on the PK within a range, there's a chance the other table is also arranged in the micro-partitions by date ranges with correlated FKs in the same range.

Using hashes eliminates this possibility because the hashing algorithms apply entropy the hashes - there's no longer any natural ordering. If you're using hashes and they're performing about the same as the original keys, either the keys don't meet the conditions to help prune or the effect is negligible. If you go with hashes, it's better to define the keys as type BINARY rather than VARCHAR.

Answer (score 1):

When data is staged include a hash column, when that data is loaded the hash column is included in the load so future comparisons compare against a single hash column that is already in the target.

Don't hash compare on the fly, it would serve little difference to do a column by column comparison, also this will simplify your code. When choosing to create a hash column make sure it is of a data type binary, binary uses half the byte length of varchar.

Comment: Thanks. And is there any recommendation on what function to use to generate the Unique Id i.e. should MD5 be used or HASH in snowflake or any other

Comment: I found MD5 doesnt handle Null values but Hash does. Are there any other functions better than these?

Comment: replace null with a blank --- use case for hash differs to md5, you can use sha1, sha2 too